# Is correct to call different api in the same moment?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm building my first big application using React. I built with Express
a Restful API to get and update data on a MySQL DB.
There is a moment when I need to get data from different tables in the same moment and populate different tables on the same page.
Is it correct to make multiple calls at the same moment? Can this cause problems?
Is there a better way to do this, like creating a dedicated API to get all the data?

I apologize in advance if there is something wrong or I was unclear

Comment: Sure, you can call different APIs concurrently.

Comment: That depends on what you need to do and how it affects your application - I don't think anyone here can answer this question for you. One thing we can answer though is that browsers have a limit of maximum number of concurrent connections to the server - I believe Chrome has a maximum of 6 - so you might have to wait for the data to show/send whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do that, but only if you are doing something ( changing Data or selecting Data ) from another Table example: Table1 apicall1 and Table2 apicall2.

If its from the same table its probably gonna screw something up if you change something big!